# Fluent nHibernate AutoMapping & ID Generation Scheme

Tags: .net, nhibernate, configuration, fluent-nhibernate, id-generation

How can I use Fluent NHibernate (with AutoMapping) to configure the default ID generation scheme to Guid.Comb?  I can see that I could specify in each entity (or a base class) the following code:

```
Id(entity => entity.Id, "Id").GuidComb();
```

Which is fine.  However this doesn't so much seem to be *setting* the default behavior as *overriding* it. I just want to know if I am missing a configuration trick.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use [conventions](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Conventions#Writing_Your_Own_Conventions).
this way you can define default behaviour which would be applied to all your classes (or conditionally, if needed).

Comment: Could you give me an example of achieving this?  I have tried creating a custom convention by implementing the implementing IClassConvention interface, but the following line of the "Apply" method give me the compiler error "Cannot resolve symbol ID": instance.Id(entity => entity.Id, "Id").GuidComb();

Comment: Got it.  Need to create a convention class that implements the IIdConvention interface.  Then in the apply method just write: instance.GeneratedBy.GuidComb();